# Counting the number of occurrences of a specific style, within a column of a table

Tags: vba, find, selection, ms-word

I need to count the number of occurrences of a specific style, within a column of a table. My program finds the number of occurrences within the whole document instead of only in the selection.

```
Sub Find()
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Style = "Style2"

        iCount = 0
        While .Execute
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Wend

        MsgBox (iCount)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of style do you need to find? If it's a paragraph style, perhaps it would be better to avoid Find. Maybe something like the following pseudocode would be enough - for each cell in the column: for each paragraph in the cell/s range: does the paragraph have that style? : next paragraph : next cell. If it's a character style, you could check the characters collection of the range of each cell, and look for changes in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing Find inside a table is a tricky proposition as Find has a nasty tendancy to "bounce" inside of a cell. When I tested your code, having no information on how the style is applied in the table cells, the macro went into a loop and didn't stop until I forced it to. So I was a bit surprised that your code worked at all...

The problem with doing find on a column is that, in the underlying structures of the document a column is not a contiguous set of characters, the way it appears on-screen. The Word table information runs top-to-bottom in the cell, left-to-right across a row, then to the next row and repeat. The column selection is an illusion maintained by the Word application. So macro code basing on Selection or Range can't follow the usual rules that apply.

The following worked for me. In essence, it searches inside the entire table, but when it hits a cell not in the specified column the target range is moved to the next cell in the column and the search is run again. Only the "hits" inside cells in the column are counted.

```
Sub FindStyleInstanceInTableColumn()
    Dim iCount As Long, iCellCount As Long, iCounter As Long
    Dim cel As word.Cell
    Dim col As word.Column
    Dim rngFind As word.Range, rngCel As word.Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Set col = Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1)
    iCount = 0
    iCellCount = col.Cells.Count
    iCounter = 1
    Set rngCel = col.Cells(iCounter).Range
    Set rngFind = rngCel.Duplicate
    'Don't include end-of-cell marker
    rngFind.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    rngFind.Select 'For debugging
    With rngFind.Find
        .Style = "Style2"
        bFound = .Execute(wrap:=wdFindStop)
        Do
            rngFind.Select  'For debugging
            If bFound Then
                'If the found range is within a column cell
                'then increase the counter
                If rngFind.InRange(rngCel) Then
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                'If the found range is not in a column cell
                'then the style wasn't found in the cell so
                'go to the next cell
                ElseIf iCounter < iCellCount Then
                    iCounter = iCounter + 1
                    Set rngCel = col.Cells(iCounter).Range
                    rngFind.Start = rngCel.Start
                    rngFind.End = rngCel.Start
                End If
                rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End If
            bFound = .Execute(Format:=True, wrap:=wdFindStop)
        Loop Until iCounter = iCellCount And Not bFound
    End With
    MsgBox (iCount)
End Sub
```

EDIT: Adjusted the code to take into account no hits in first cell and hits in the last cell of the column. The difference is to make sure the starting point for rngFind is in the same cell as rngCel.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tested the code on my data, it works when the specified style can be found in the first cell. However, the macro goes into an infinite loop, if nothing is found in the first cell (it continues searching in the first cell). I added a few lines to overcome the loop issue; the search now continues toward the next cells successfully. But still, even though the "rngFind" is forced to be updated, the ".Execute" command returns the search result within the first cell (bFound is not updated). I would be grateful if you give a hint in this regard!